# c++ default constructor constexpr or properly undefined?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, default-constructor

Is it better to declare a default constructor which:

- Allocates default values to the member data and is declared constexpr, or
- leaves all member data undefined?

I'm thinking mainly in the context of STL containers, e.g. vectors make heavy use of default constructors, so which way is more efficient?

Comment: null constructor?? Do you mean the default constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can call it that if you like.  `Default' is overloaded these days, I prefer to refer to the one which doesn't take any arguments as the null constructor.

Comment: I like how you phrase that, as if generously allowing us to use the proper terminology that will actually be understood by other programmers.

Comment: ["Impenetrability! That's what I say!"](https://www.fecundity.com/pmagnus/humpty.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like all things in C++, it depends.

Are you intending to create large buffers of this and both need the optimization of not clearing the memory *and* are unwilling to put the effort towards allocating unallocated memory yourself?

Or do you want your programs to be correct more often?

Put that way, default your member data and constexpr your constructor.  There are ways that involve a few hoops where you can declare a buffer of uninitialized memory large enough to hold N copies of your class and initialize the data later.  (It is true there is no standard compliant portable way to implement `std::vector` yourself, but that is a defect in the standard that won't impact you in real life very soon.)

Comment: I think I'm in the former mind-set, though was hoping there'd be an answer for the general case.  Hmmm, I guess I can't expect to get a clearer answer than that, thanks.